# Display View in Simplenews Email

Tags: views, 6, emails

I have a view block on my frontpage ('news-block') that displays 3 headings which are links to the 3 latest news articles in my website (content-type = 'news').

How do I display this view block in my Simplenews? Alternative suggestions are welcome. I assume this data will display whatever it is at the time of sending, which is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you want, you can either use a module like [Insert View](http://drupal.org/project/insert_view) that allows to embed views as a token inside the newsletter body (dynamically, you can choose the view per newsletter issue) or you override the newsletter body template and embed the view there using [views_embed_view()](http://ericlondon.com/embedding-view-drupal-6-using-views-embed-view) (hardcoded per newsletter category).

Comment: Thanks mate. I actually tried the views_embed_view() earlier but it didn't work, actually gave me errors. Has this syntax been updated?

Comment: I can't help if you show neither the code you tried nor the errors you received. You might want to create a new question for that.

Comment: I didn't receive any errors, as the page itself wouldn't load! I'll try the syntax suggested in the page and let you know how I go.